# How to apply dynamic data to a pie chart in echarts?

Tags: echarts

I have two arrays of data: [35, 15, 30] and [green, red, blue] assigned to single variables "freqs" and "colors". One for the values in the pie chart and one for the names. The two variables are being passed into the page.

This situation is no problem with echarts bar and line charts because both x and y axes have a "data" component, but for pie charts I can't find any examples of how to display the names.

Most pie chart examples look something like:

```
series: [
        {
            name: 'Color Frequencies',
            type: 'pie',
            radius: '55%',
            center: ['50%', '60%'],
            data: [
                {value: 335, name: '直接访问'},
                {value: 310, name: '邮件营销'},
                {value: 234, name: '联盟广告'},
                {value: 135, name: '视频广告'},
                {value: 1548, name: '搜索引擎'}
            ],
        }
    ]
```

If I try:

```
series: [
        {
            name: 'Color Frequencies',
            type: 'pie',
            radius: '55%',
            center: ['50%', '60%'],
            data: freqs
        }
    ]
```

the data displays fine, but without any category labels. I have tried `data: [freqs, colors]`, or some variant, it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
myChart.setOption({series: [...]})
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm unclear on this. I already have everything in an option block and have `myChart.setOption(option);`  That displays the values fine. I should add a second one for the category labels variable?

Comment: Could you publish your code with jsfiddle?

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

The Pie need data likes:

```
...
data:  [
        {value:35, name:'green'},
        {value:15, name:'red'},
        {value:30, name:'blue'},
],
...
```

[image: pie]